# Can I have a single service created to expose as both cluster IP and NodePort?

Tags: kubernetes

I have 2 pods running on minikube. Pod A has to `expose 2 ports` 8081 and 9092 to both Pod B `inside the k8 cluster` and also `outside k8 cluster` so that pod B can reach them and also outside the cluster my consumer can reach them.So my question is `should` I have `2 services` created for each port?
One to expose as cluster ip and one for node port? Or is there a way to have a single service created to expose this as both cluster IP and NodePort?

Also if I have to expose my node port as a particular port, would specifying `nodePort` mess up with the cluster ip?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you choose the `NodePort` service type, besides having a Cluster IP, kubernetes will expose the service on a port on each node of the cluster (the same port on each node). So choosing NodePort gets you both: the ClusterIP and the port on each node.
As said [in the docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#type-nodeport)

> Note that this Service will be visible as both :spec.ports[*].nodePort and spec.clusterIP:spec.ports[*].port.